# $(window).scroll() Loop, due to no variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bit of a problem; I have this code:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.services-container').offset().top-80) {
      alert("test");
    }
  });
```

Now everything works ok, except I need to run the if statement once, I tried variables but I cannot get them not to re-set to previous state due to the window scroll loop... any help?

Comment: Hello, could you be more precise? Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use;

```
var enabled = true;
$(window).scroll(
    function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.services-container').offset().top-80 && enabled) {
            alert("test");
            enabled = false;
        }
    }
);
```

Here is working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66jz7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some flag:

```
var flag = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.services-container').offset().top-80 && flag) {
       alert("test");
       flag = false;
    }
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVf6r/)

Comment: Oops.. the alert keeps on changing it back, due to document ready? I think, I removed the alert and checked in debug mode and it seems that it doesn't re-set :) thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flag = true;
$(window).scroll(
    function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.services-container').offset().top-80 && flag) {
            flag = false;
            alert("test");
        }
    }
);
```